# Does a continuous verb form avoids a comma splice?

Tags: punctuation

I realize this question has been done to death but I'm still questioning it.

The following sentence I feel does not contain a comma splice as the clause doesn't seem to hold up on its own:

> Most European countries have proceeded with significant liberalization of financial law since the 1980s, **Ireland being the latest example**.

However, when I write it slightly differently, I'm pretty positive it is a comma splice.

> Most European countries have proceeded with significant liberalization of financial law since the 1980s, **Ireland is no exception**.

Is this correct? And if so, why? Why does the continuous form make it not a comma splice. If it is indeed a comma splice, how would you punctuate it to capture the informal style of the author. An em dash, a semi-colon, a full-stop or *and*?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please define "comma splice" as you understand it.

Comment: The normal definition of a comma splice is a comma that separates two independent clauses. In your case, what comes after the comma could stand on its own as an independent clause. So, yes. The second example would normally be considered a comma splice. That doesn't necessarily mean that it's wrong to use it. however. Some instances of comma splices are acceptable. (Although in this case, my personal preference would be to add an *and* after it.)

Comment: @JasonBassford "I came, I saw, and I conquered."

Comment: @tchrist That's not a comma splice because of the final conjunctive *and*.  Without the *and* it would be.

Comment: @JasonBassford Are you claiming that omitting the *and* would somehow be an error??

Comment: @tchrist Not at all. I'm just saying it would be a comma splice. As I said, some comma splices are acceptable. Either in the case of very short clauses or writing to stylistic effect.

Answer (score 3):

*Ireland being the latest example* is not in "the continuous form", which is constructed with a form of *BE* followed by the present participle. For that clause to "hold up on its own"—that is, constitute an independent clause—it would have to have that *BE* in a finite (tensed) form: in this case, the 3d person singular form *is*.

The clause is thus a subordinate clause, headed by a non-finite verbform, and the "comma splice rule" does not apply.

Comment: Feels a bit like a gerund clause appositive to the sentence's subject,

Comment: @tchrist Mmm ... I'd see it as a supplemental clause which in effect "modifies" the entire matrix clause. Ireland isn't an example of *many European countries* but of many European countries which have proceeded &c.

Comment: Sure, I didn't say it was one, just that it had some of that feel. Certainly it applies to the entire independent clause not just the subject alone..